# Rejecting changes in table is too slow

Tags: vba, ms-word

I am collecting revised and original text from documents. I do it by iterating through every sentence.

This works fine (except that sentence are often broken by the revisions themselves), but I am getting a HUGE performace hit when the documents contain lots of tables.

I'm talking a few hundred times longer than other files.

I used breakpoints to find that the perfo hit is around the sentence.revisions.rejectAll instruction. Each will take a few seconds.

Also, I take the two versions of text and write them into a spreadsheet.

Is there a trick anyone know of when working with revisions and tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I was able to figure out, using different documents, rejecting revisions on tables are slow. Dead slow.

At first I thought the hit was largely due to formating revisions, but it is not the case. A document with 68 mixed revisions took 35 seconds to run. A similar one with 22 revisions took 23 seconds.

A document with just text revisions took about 4 minutes @ 178 revisions.

I also tried mixing a text document inside a table-filled one, and the performance was only as slow as when I did them separately (meaning there was no more impact from the text as when it was not in the table-filled document).

My conclusions are revision inside tables are slow to reject. Possibly due to the need to rearrange the layout after each change.